# How to parse response from multipart form data request in retrofit2 android

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I'm using Retrofit 2 to create a multipart form-data request which works ok and the Server responds 200. I have problems to parse the response. Here is my code:

```
@POST("sync/mediaUpload")
@Multipart
Call<ResponseBody> uploadMediaFile(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                                          @Part("userId") RequestBody userId,
                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                          @Part("fileId") RequestBody photoId,
                                          @Part("hash") RequestBody hash);


public Response<ResponseBody> uploadMediaFile(String token, String userId, File file, String fileName, String fileId, String hash) {

    MediaService service = retrofit.create(MediaService.class);
    MultipartBody.Part fileBody = prepareFilePart("file", file);
    RequestBody userIdBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), userId);
    RequestBody fileNameBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), fileName);
    RequestBody fileIdBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), fileId);
    RequestBody hashBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), hash);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.uploadMediaFile(token, userIdBody, txIdBody, transIdBody, stepCodeBody,
            fileBody, fileNameBody, fileIdBody, hashBody);
    try {
        return call.execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

 @NonNull
private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, File file) {
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
}
```

The Server returns a Json object when the file is uploaded correctly. Example:

```
{
    "fileName": "IMG_20190108_183751.jpg",
    "fileId": "0",
    "fileSizeInBytes": 216067
}
```

but, in call.execute(), retrofit returns:

```
--MultipartDataMediaFormatterBoundary1q2w3e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileName"
IMG_20190108_183751.jpg

--MultipartDataMediaFormatterBoundary1q2w3e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileId"
0

--MultipartDataMediaFormatterBoundary1q2w3e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileSizeInBytes"
216067
```

How do I parse that response?
I tried to change the signature of retrofit service for using an object instead of ResponseBody:

```
@POST("sync/mediaUpload")
@Multipart
Call<MediaUploadResponse> uploadMediaFile(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                                          @Part("userId") RequestBody userId,
                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                          @Part("fileId") RequestBody photoId,
                                          @Part("hash") RequestBody hash);
```

And my Object

```
public class MediaUploadResponse {

public final String fileName;
public final String fileId;
public final long fileSizeInBytes;

    public MediaUploadResponse(String fileName, String fileId, long 
    fileSizeInBytes) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileId = fileId;
        this.fileSizeInBytes = fileSizeInBytes;
    }
}
```

but Retrofit throws MalformedJsonException

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer I will give you will use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) [streaming](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming) (streaming for the speed) and [okhttp3](https://github.com/square/okhttp). Please remember that this code as it is currently displayed was not tested. It is to show you the idea of what to do. I took it from one of my currently running app (the idea is implemented and working). It might look like an overkill. I you have another question because of a blur point, leave a comment below.

1- Setup GSON with retrofit:

```
package whatever.package.you.want;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.converter.scalars.ScalarsConverterFactory;

public class DataService {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 45;//s
    private static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 45;//s
    private static final int WRITE_TIMEOUT = 45;//s
    private static final String MEDIA_TYPE = "application/json";//"multipart/form-data"; //"text/plain";
    private static final DATA_SERVICE_BASE_URL = "https://stackoverflow.com"; // your desired URL
    //I suppose you have your custom declarations here

    public static Retrofit getClient(String yourURL) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();

        //https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor
        /*HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);*/

        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                /*.addInterceptor(logging)*/
                .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                .build();

        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(yourURL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)) //https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()) //https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/scalars
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

    public static DataService getUserDataService() {
        return getClient(DATA_SERVICE_BASE_URL).create(UserDataServiceInterface.class);
    }
}
```

2- Your model `MediaUploadResponse.class` :

```
package whatever.package.you.want;

import com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;


@JsonAdapter(MediaUploadResponseAdapter.class)
public class MediaUploadResponse {

    @SerializedName("fileName")
    private String fileName = "";

    @SerializedName("fileId")
    private String fileID = "";

    @SerializedName("fileSizeInBytes")
    private long fileSizeInBytes = "";


    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getFileId() {
        return fileId;
    }

    public void setFileId(String fileId) {
        this.fileId = fileId;
    }

    public String getFileSizeInBytes() {
        return fileSizeInBytes;
    }

    public void setFileSizeInBytes(long fileSizeInBytes) {
        this.fileSizeInBytes = fileSizeInBytes;
    }
}
```

3- The model's adapter `MediaUploadResponseAdapter.class`, for serializing and deserializing:

```
package whatever.package.you.want;

import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import whatever.MediaUploadResponse;
import whatever.JsonAdapterUtils;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MediaUploadResponseAdapter extends BaseJsonAdapter<MediaUploadResponse> {

    @Override
    public MediaUploadResponse read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        MediaUploadResponse element = new MediaUploadResponse();
        String fieldName = null;

        if(reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL){
            reader.nextNull();
            return null;
        }

        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            JsonToken token = reader.peek();
            if(token.equals(JsonToken.NAME))
                fieldName = reader.nextName();

            if (fieldName.equals("fileName") && token != JsonToken.NULL)
                element.setFileName(JsonAdapterUtils.stringFromJsonReader(reader));

            else if (fieldName.equals("fileId") && token != JsonToken.NULL)
                element.setFileID(JsonAdapterUtils.stringFromJsonReader(reader));

            else if (fieldName.equals("fileSizeInBytes") && token != JsonToken.NULL)
                element.SetFileSizeInBytes(JsonAdapterUtils.longFromJsonReader(reader));

            else
                reader.skipValue();
        }
        reader.endObject();

        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter writer, MediaUploadResponse element) throws IOException {
        if(element == null){
            writer.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        writer.beginObject();
        writer.name("fileName").value(element.getFileName());
        writer.name("fileId").value(element.getFileId());
        writer.name("fileSizeInBytes").value(element.getFileSizeInBytes());
        writer.endObject();
    }
}
```

4- Use this call (the second you posted) (**EDIT: Here is the answer to the main problem**):

```
@Headers({
        "Accept: application/json"
})
@POST("sync/mediaUpload")
@Multipart
Call<MediaUploadResponse> uploadMediaFile(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                                          @Part("userId") RequestBody userId,
                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                          @Part("fileId") RequestBody photoId,
                                          @Part("hash") RequestBody hash);
```

5- Some bonuses so that you don't miss some dependencies:

a- The `BaseJsonAdapter.class` class (will help to parse lists):

```
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by mamboa on 3/6/2018.
 */

public class BaseJsonAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<T>{

    public ArrayList<T> readArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        if(reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL){
            reader.nextNull();
            return null;
        }

        ArrayList<T> elements = new ArrayList<T>();

        reader.beginArray();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            T value = read(reader);
            if(value != null)
                elements.add(value);
            else {
             break;
            }
        }
        reader.endArray();
        return elements;
    }

    public void writeArray(JsonWriter writer, List<T> messages) throws IOException {
        writer.beginArray();
        for (T message : messages) {
            write(writer, message);
        }
        writer.endArray();
    }

    public T read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }

    public void write(JsonWriter writer, T t) throws IOException {
    }
}
```

b- And finally the `JsonAdapterUtils`:

```
package whatever.Utils;


import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by mamboa on 3/7/2018.
 */

public class JsonAdapterUtils {

    public static final int INTEGER_DEFAULT = -1;
    public static final String STRING_DEFAULT = "";
    public static final boolean BOOLEAN_DEFAULT = false;

    public static int intFromJsonReader(JsonReader reader) throws IOException{
        try {
            if(reader.peek() == JsonToken.BOOLEAN)
                return  fromBooleanToInt(reader.nextBoolean());

            String resultValue = reader.nextString();
            if("".equals(resultValue))
                return INTEGER_DEFAULT;

            return Integer.parseInt(resultValue);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            return returnDefaultAfterException(reader);
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException ex){
            return returnDefaultAfterException(reader);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            return returnDefaultAfterException(reader);
        }
    }

    public static long longFromJsonReader(JsonReader reader) throws IOException{
        try {
            if(reader.peek() == JsonToken.BOOLEAN)
                return  fromBooleanToInt(reader.nextBoolean());

            String resultValue = reader.nextString();
            if("".equals(resultValue))
                return INTEGER_DEFAULT;

            return Long.parseLong(resultValue);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            return returnDefaultAfterException(reader);
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException ex){
            return returnDefaultAfterException(reader);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            return returnDefaultAfterException(reader);
        }
    }

    public static float floatFromJsonReader(JsonReader reader) throws IOException{
        try {
            if(reader.peek() == JsonToken.BOOLEAN)
                return  fromBooleanToInt(reader.nextBoolean());

            String resultValue = reader.nextString();
            if("".equals(resultValue))
                return INTEGER_DEFAULT;

            return Float.parseFloat(resultValue);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            return returnDefaultAfterException(reader);
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException ex){
            return returnDefaultAfterException(reader);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            return returnDefaultAfterException(reader);
        }
    }

    public static double doubleFromJsonReader(JsonReader reader) throws IOException{
        try {
            if(reader.peek() == JsonToken.BOOLEAN)
                return  fromBooleanToInt(reader.nextBoolean());

            String resultValue = reader.nextString();
            if("".equals(resultValue))
                return INTEGER_DEFAULT;

            return Double.parseDouble(resultValue);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            return returnDefaultAfterException(reader);
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException ex){
            return returnDefaultAfterException(reader);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            return returnDefaultAfterException(reader);
        }
    }

    public static String stringFromJsonReader(JsonReader reader) throws IOException{
        String resultValue = "";
        try {
            if(reader.peek() == JsonToken.BOOLEAN)
                return  boolFromJsonReader(reader)? "true" : "false";

            resultValue = reader.nextString();
            return  !resultValue.equals("") ? resultValue : STRING_DEFAULT;
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            reader.skipValue();
            return STRING_DEFAULT;
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException ex){
            reader.skipValue();
            return STRING_DEFAULT;
        }
    }

    public static boolean boolFromJsonReader(JsonReader reader)throws IOException{
        try {
            if(reader.peek() == JsonToken.BOOLEAN)
                return  reader.peek() == JsonToken.BOOLEAN ? reader.nextBoolean() : BOOLEAN_DEFAULT;
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            reader.skipValue();
        }
        return BOOLEAN_DEFAULT;
    }

    private static int returnDefaultAfterException(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        if(reader != null) reader.skipValue();
        return INTEGER_DEFAULT;
    }

    private static int fromBooleanToInt(boolean value){
        return value ? 1 : 0;
    }

    public static String serializeObject(Object object){
        if(object != null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            return gson.toJson(object);
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

**EDIT: The problem:**

The problem is that in the http request's parameters, the server has to know that the caller wants the response in the JSON format. 
So the **solution** with [Retrofit 2](https://square.github.io/retrofit/),when using `Multipart` is to add the following (on top of the request):

```
@Headers({
        "Accept: application/json"
})
```

Comment: I changed my code, using your modifications but is not working. I get an exception in MediaUploadResponseAdapter in method "read":

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: If you get this error, it might be that your Json is not starting by `{`. Can you check it please. The second thing, in the adapter class, in the `read()` place a break point on each line that starts by `element.set...` to detect exactly what is broken.

Comment: But I don´t know exactly where is the json response. It seems that retrofit does not recognize the json format. In the buffer of jsonReader I see --MultipartDataMediaFormatterBoundary1q2w3e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileName" IMG_20190108_183751.jpg.... For this reason throws an exception in "reader.beginObject();". Postman shows in response body { "fileName": "IMG_20190108_183751.jpg", "fileId": "0", "fileSizeInBytes": 216067 }

Comment: @JavierHinmel please if it is not confidential, give me the postman example (request, url and parameters), and I will investigate, write a little project and try. Then when I find the problem I will tell you.

Comment: Do you have `.setLenient()` in your `GsonBuilder()`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your collaboration Maxime!. Yes, I´m using setLenient() in my GsonBuilder. You can test my ws from Postman, sending a post to: [link](http://amazon.inalambrik.com.ar/maapi/sync/mediaUpload), choosing **form-data** as content type and in body, you have to put the next parameters: **file** (choose any file.jpg), **filename** =test.jpg, **userId** =TEST, **photoId** =0

Comment: I tried post man as you required, it gave me a 500 http error. Here is a [screenshot](https://ibb.co/hV68hxr). Did I miss something?

Comment: mmm...I don't find any error in your request. [Here is my request in postman](https://ibb.co/zPx1yGf). I changed the web api server method so that not throws exception. Please, try again. Thanks!

Comment: Try to test the post with an image less than 300 kb

Comment: I received this `{
    "errorMessage": "File es requerido"
}`  with the 412 error (Precondition failed)

Comment: It seems that postman is not sending the file in the post. I can reproduce the same error when I don´t choose any file in post request. Please, check if you don´t missed to attach the file to the request.

Comment: I don't understand how the server is set. I have discovered the problem. The problem is  that when we try in postman, it returns the answer as a JSON. Yet, when I try on the emulator the server's response is not a JSON, it is a String. Look [what](https://ibb.co/F6NSGbt) i had, it is not a JSON.

Comment: Look the point **4-** of my answer, I added `@Headers({
            "Accept: application/json"
    })` on top of the method. Now it is working for me. You can see it [here](https://ibb.co/LPYRqJK). Try it please.

Comment: Thank you very much Maxime!. Now it´s working. I appreciate your support.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It worked for me. However, I realised that maybe I could just ask the server to respond with a JSON (@Headers({
        "Accept: application/json"
})) in the first place. And yes, that solved my problem with the multipart response and I didn't have to implement anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and realised that I could ask the server to respond with a JSON (`@Headers`):

```
@Headers({
        "Accept: application/json"
})
@POST("sync/mediaUpload")
@Multipart
Call<MediaUploadResponse> uploadMediaFile(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                                          @Part("userId") RequestBody userId,
                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                          @Part("fileId") RequestBody photoId,
                                          @Part("hash") RequestBody hash);
```